Azure Pipelines - Best practices for scheduled pipelines?
I have a ci/cd YAML pipeline for deploying my Kubernetes cluster. I also have a separate YAML pipeline for upsizing and downsizing my cluster.
My upsize and downsize YAML retrieves the current deployed build for each environment since our repo only has a master branch. This ensures we are not deploying any new helm values that haven't been deployed to the environments yet (dev, stage and prod).
Should I continue to keep separate YAML pipelines or condense it into a single pipeline? Is there any best practice for this or is it really up to the team's preference?


Should I continue to keep separate YAML files or condense it into a single pipeline?

If by "YAML files" you mean templates then I'd suggest to use Templates Everywhere.
More details
Use templates to to hide complex implementation details and reuse logic and configuration within or across pipelines.
Logic (aka functionality) templates:

Steps: define a sequence of steps that can be reused across jobs, or referenced in another steps template.- Jobs: define one or more jobs that can be reused across stages or pipelines.
Stages: define one or more stages that can be reused across pipelines.

Configuration templates:

Variables: define a set of variables that can be reused across jobs, stages or pipelines.

Example:
variables:
  - template: /pipelines/variables/common-variables.yaml

pool: 
  name: $(agentPool)

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build and publish Docker image
    jobs:
      - job: BuildAndPushDocker
        displayName: Build and push Docker image
        variables:
          - template: /pipelines/variables/docker-variables.yaml
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - template: /pipelines/steps/build-push-docker-steps.yaml
            parameters:
              workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
              # ...

  - stage: DeployDev
    displayName: Deploy to Dev
    dependsOn: Build
    jobs:
      - job: DeployDev
        displayName: Deploy to Dev
        variables:
          # reference environment-specific variables here
          - template: /pipelines/variables/dev-variables.yaml
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - template: /pipelines/steps/deploy-helm-chart-steps.yaml
            parameters:
              # use variables from /pipelines/variables/dev-variables.yaml
              chart: $(chart)
              namespace: $(namespace)
              valuesFile: $(valuesFile)
              # ...

  - stage: DeployStage
    displayName: Deploy to Stage
    dependsOn: DeployDev
    jobs:
      - job: DeployStage
        displayName: Deploy to Stage
        variables:
          # reference environment-specific variables here
          - template: /pipelines/variables/stage-variables.yaml
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - template: /pipelines/steps/deploy-helm-chart-steps.yaml
            parameters:
              # use variables from /pipelines/variables/stage-variables.yaml
              chart: $(chart)
              namespace: $(namespace)
              valuesFile: $(valuesFile)
              # ...

  - stage: DeployProd
    displayName: Deploy to Prod
    dependsOn: DeployStage
    jobs:
      - job: DeployProd
        displayName: Deploy to Prod
        variables:
          # reference environment-specific variables here
          - template: /pipelines/variables/prod-variables.yaml
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - template: /pipelines/steps/deploy-helm-chart-steps.yaml
            parameters:
              # use variables from /pipelines/variables/prod-variables.yaml
              chart: $(chart)
              namespace: $(namespace)
              valuesFile: $(valuesFile)
              # ...

The above pipeline uses steps and variable templates which allow us to reuse functionality such as deploying a Helm chart, using different configuration for each environment.
Templates for the jobs or stages could have been created as well.

No, I am already using templates. But I have more than one azure-pipelines.yaml in my repo. So one being the ci/cd one, and then another one for upsize/downsizing on a schedule. Should I keep it separate or integrate it into my cicd pipeline yaml and add a schedule?

@AnnNguyen you should have written separate YAML pipelines as opposed to separate YAML files to avoid confusion.


Should I continue to keep separate YAML pipelines or condense it into a single pipeline? Is there any best practice for this or is it really up to the team's preference?

You need to consider the degree of dependency between the pipelines. If they often need to run one after another, then combining them might make sense. But if they’re very independent and do not interfere with each other, then keeping them separate might be a good choice.
In fact, the goal of CI/CD is to make your development process smoother and more efficient. Therefore, the best practice is the one that suits your team best. So, you can try and see what works best in practice. Then you can get feedback from your team and make improvements.
